# AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'mesh'

Tags: attributeerror

I am a beginner with fipy and python.

I have tried to run the transientTerm equation in fipy (as given in the FiPy Manual Release 3.1.3) to which i have added a mesh and i asked for an output.
I got this error : AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'mesh'
I don't know what to do.

Please for help!

Thank you in advance.

The complete code is :

```
from fipy import *
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from fipy.meshes import Grid1D
nx=100
L=10.
mesh=Grid1D(dx=L / 100, nx=nx)

phi0 = 0.0031
k = 1.
dt = 1.
relaxationFactor = 1.5
steps = 2
sweeps = 8

from fipy.variables.cellVariable import CellVariable
var = CellVariable(mesh = mesh, value = phi0, hasOld = 1)
valueLeft = 0.
valueRight = 0.
var.constrain(valueLeft, mesh.facesLeft)
var.constrain(valueRight, mesh.facesRight)

from fipy.terms.transientTerm import TransientTerm
from fipy.terms.implicitSourceTerm import ImplicitSourceTerm
#Relaxation, given by relaxationFactor, is required for a converged solution.
eq = TransientTerm(var) == ImplicitSourceTerm(-relaxationFactor) \
    + var * relaxationFactor + k
#A number of sweeps at each time step are required to let the relaxation take effect.
for step in range(steps):
    var.updateOld()
    for sweep in range(sweeps):
        eq.solve(var, dt = dt)
#Compare the final result with the analytical solution.
from fipy.tools import numerix
analyticalArray = numerix.sqrt(k * dt * steps + phi0**2)
print(var.allclose(analyticalArray, rtol=1e-4, atol=1e-4))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   viewer = Viewer(vars=(var, analyticalArray),)
   viewer.plot()
```

The modifications made to the code I took from the manual are :
I added a 1D mesh at the beginning of the code and I asked for the plot to be shown.